# using same delegate in LINQ Where(x => f(x) > y) and OrderBy(f) with SQL compilation

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I'm attempting to write a relatively simple but general pagination function for EFCore, and am having trouble finding the right function type to make sure that my sort-key selector is translated to SQL for both the `Where` and `OrderBy` clauses.

```
    public List<TItem> GetPage<TItem>(IQueryable<TItem> items, TFunc keyExtractor, int? itemsAfter = default)
    {
        if (itemsAfter != default)
        {
            items = items.Where(item => keyExtractor(item) > itemsAfter);
        }

        var materialized = items.OrderBy(keyExtractor).Take(pageSize).ToList();

        // ... stuff to trim page size ...
    }
```

- when `TFunc` is `Expression<Func<TItem, int>>`, it's properly handled in `OrderBy` but the `Where` clause must be changed to `keyExtractor.Compile().Invoke(item) > itemsAfter` and is not translated, giving me "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query: Warning: The LINQ expression 'where (Convert(__Compile_1.Invoke([t]), Nullable`1) > __itemsAfter_2)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally."
- when `TFunc` is `Func<TItem, int>`, it is properly handled by the `Where` clause but the `OrderBy` uses `IEnumerable.OrderBy` rather than `IQueryable.OrderBy`.  This means that the order & take are done locally - which is fine for the top-level object itself, but child properties do not take the `Take` into account and pull an enormous amount of data.

Is there a better way to convert one of these to the other, such that the query will be translated? Or is there a third type I can accept that could be easily made into these two types?  My keyExtractor parameters are all relatively simple, e.g. `item => item.id`.   Due to reasons outside of my control, I'm currently stuck with EFCore 2.1

Comment: Do you have automatic client side evaluation [disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#previous-versions)? Cause the `Func<TItem, int>` case seems very suspitious to actually handle `Where` on client side.

Comment: Show in question samples of the usage. Does `keyExtractor` accept just one field?

Comment: @GuruStron unfortunately it's a large inherited codebase without testing - we haven't been able to get it in shape to disable client-side evaluation yet.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv I did include a sample what gets passed to `keyExtractor` - `item => item.id`.  The extractor takes one TItem and returns an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Expression<Func<TItem, int>>` you need to build greater than expression yourself. Something along this lines:

```
public List<TItem> GetPage<TItem>(IQueryable<TItem> items, Expression<Func<TItem, int>> keyExtractor, int? itemsAfter = default)
{
    if (itemsAfter != default)
    {
        var greaterThan = Expression.GreaterThan(keyExtractor.Body, Expression.Constant(itemsAfter));
        var filter = Expression.Lambda<Func<TItem, bool>>(greaterThan, keyExtractor.Parameters);
        items = items.Where(filter);
    }
     var materialized = items.OrderBy(keyExtractor).Take(pageSize).ToList();
     // ... stuff to trim page size ...

}
```